# "the ... of a" classifying expressions

Tags: definite-article, indefinite-article, of-phrases

On p. 62 of the 2nd edition of *Practical English Usage*, M. Swan writes:

> 68 articles (8): special rules and exceptions
>
> ---

> ***4 the ... of a ...***

> In classifying expressions of this kind, the first article is definite
> even if the meaning of the whole expression is indefinite:

> *Lying by the side of the road we saw the wheel of a car. (NOT ...**a** wheel of a car.)*

However, this entry is missing from the 3rd and the 4th editions. Moreover, dictionaries give these examples:

> She got *a glimpse of a* very different way of life.

> the management and disposition of *the property of a* deceased person, debtor, or insolvent company, by a legally appointed administrator

> The phones are considered to be *the property of the* company.

---

Why is this rule not included in the modern editions? If the rule is not valid anymore, does it mean than the choice of *a/the* obeys general rules say:

> We choose a property of a system... (random property of some system)

> We investigate the property of a system... (some very interesting
> property mentioned earlier of some random system) ?

Comment: Could you state the whole rule from the second edition? Anyway, *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* by Huddleston & Pullum (2002, pp.368–9) tells us *the* can be used when it's not necessary clear **which one** we mean when we don't really care which one. While you could ask *Which one (wheel)?*, the speaker assumes you won't because it's not really important. Likewise, *Open the window* can be said when there are multiple closed windows in a room. Secondly, *the* is used with *wheel(s)* because we know exactly which wheels we're talking about – those on a car.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way to understand this usage is to forget the grammar rules for a while and look at some actual examples to illustrate what grammar books say.

- **We saw the wheel of a car**.

the X of a Y: Basically this functions as explained below.

If you say:  |**I saw the wheel of a car**|  the implication is, in a conversation or if you are telling story, that you **did not see** the wheel of some other thing: **the wheel of a cart, the wheel of a ship**, etc.

It is not that the whole thing is indefinite. The car is random, the wheel belonging to it is not. Or the wheel is closely associated with it. Here are some more examples:

- **We read the introduction of a book**.
  Compare: We read the introduction of an essay.
- **We broke off the  handle of a coffeepot.**
  Compare: We broke off the handle of a door.

**The idea here is that the determiner *the* goes with a noun that is closely associated with the second noun in the prepositional phrase** in a given context.

- The professor **explained the idea of a philosopher**, not **the ravings of a madman.**
- Schrödinger explained the idea of a cat as both alive and dead at the same time.

**When both are indefinite and not necessarily associated with each other in a context, you can get two a's**.

- She got **a glimpse** of **a very different kind of life**.
- He mentioned **a work of art of a kind** we had not heard of before.

Similarly, both can be definite [that's just a short-hand word].

- The boats in the harbor are the boats of **the men on the** dock.
- Those classroom methods were the ideas of **the teachers of the primary school**. [not the high school, for example.]

Comment: Thanks. That what I meant by writing 'general rule': If something is 'unique' (obviously, a book has only one introduction), it's *the*. If it's one of many (a work of art) it's *a*.

Comment: the introduction of a book is not the introduction of something else. There is an **implied exclusion**. the X of  a Y excludes all variables that are not a Y.